# Stdout showing empty result after code is compiled in exec method nodejs

Tags: java, node.js

I am creating a childprocess to compile java code in nodeJs.
Below is the code

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;  
    let file1 = 'Hello.java'
    let file2 = 'C:/Development/vilearn/vilearn_node/src'
    let file3 = 'Hello'
exec('"C:/Development/vilearn/vilearn_node/src/my.bat" '+file1+' '+file2+' '+file3+'',(err, stdout, stderr) => {  
      if (err) {  
        console.error(err);  
        return;  
      }  
      output = stdout
      console.log(stdout,"out1");  
    });
```

Below is my batch file where i have written commands to compile java files

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin
cd %2
pwd
javac %1
java %3
```

Code compiles successfully and prints the output in console but when i do a 
**console.log(stdout,"out1");**  the output will be empty.

Am i going wrong somewhere?

Help appreciated!

Comment: try `console.log(stderr);` to see if there is any error

Comment: Thanks for your reply, even stderr shows empty. Is it due to async property of exec  method?

Comment: Would it be the \  and  /  difference? Have you tried replacing / with \\ in the code?